# Postgres- Get the count of an element GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I've a table:-

```
id        value
1           1
1           2
1           1
1           4
2           1
2           3
2           2
3           1
4           2
```

I want to get the id and their respective count having value = 1, ie For the above table, the output should be the following:-

```
id        count
1           2
2           1
3           1
4           0
```

Since, id = 1 has 2 entries of 1, id = 2 has 1 entry of 1, similarly id 3 has 1 entry, id 4 has 0 entry.

I'm get the following output using the following que:-

```
select id,count(value) 
from table                                                               
where value=1
group by id
order by count(value);

id        count
1           2
2           1
3           1
```

I want to get the `4, 0` entry as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
select id,sum(case when value ='1' then 1 else 0 end) as val
from table    
group by id
order by id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does `sum(case when value ='1' then 1 else 0 end)` do?

Comment: when value is 1 then its return 1 else it will return 0.

Answer (score 1):

You try this Sql Query

```
select id,COUNT(CASE WHEN value = '1' THEN 1 END) count
from tablename    
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the where clause that remove the row id=4

try following:

```
select id,sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as count 
from table             
group by id
order by sum(case when value = 1 then 1 else 0 end);
```